# How to mine any coin with computers on a network?

Tags: miner-configuration

I have a network that I fully own with around 55 computers. I have heard of the ways malicious websites have used CPU power to mine for them with code in their sites.

Since I have full ownership of these computers, and they are not being used past a certain time every day (4pm but they remain on 24/7) how can I set up a program in which I don't necessarily have to install a program such as NiceHash or MinerGate on every single computer, and take advantage of these computers still being on, connected to my domain?

Comment: Malware *does* install on host computers, albeit secretly. I don't see how you can run a process on a computer without installing it on that computer. There's some javascript miners that run in a browser, so that's like a quasi-install.

Comment: I completely understand, I mean to ask how can I configure any and all computers on the domain to mine? Without the process of installing and setting up software like you would if you had a mining rig, but yet in the same sense of those with access to the malware websites had.

Comment: Malware is basically remote administration software but sneakier.  With 55 computers, surely you already have some good remote administration solution?  You'd create a script or whatever to install and automatically start the software on all of them.  Just like if you wanted to install any other program (web server, word processor, etc) on all of them.

Comment: Malware gets the remote admin software installed in the first place via some sort of exploit in a browser or other software, or by tricking the user into running it. If this is possible on your network then you're already doing something wrong. But again it shouldn't be necessary because you presumably already have some convenient way to get the machines to do whatever you need, with your authorization.

Comment: @NateEldredge Thanks Nate, I do understand that aspect of it, but in terms of which program to use, and how I would get each machine to mine to a specific address, is where I am confused. Yes I have the Administration software, and yes I would need to provide my authorization which I can, but the direction of how to start and then point to an address is where I am having trouble

Comment: Keep in mind that even though the computers are on, having them mine will substantially increase their power consumption and likewise their heat output (meaning you need more air conditioning to keep the temperature under control).  Expect to see a bump in your energy bills.  Unless your machines are pretty carefully configured for efficiency, it's very likely this will exceed any revenue you earn from mining.  If their cooling isn't adequate, also expect to see machines failing or running unreliably due to overheat.

Comment: @NateEldredge I do understand that, but for a month test im sure we will be able to withstand.. not worried about electricity or ac through this situation as of right now